# Why /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com)|(edu)|(org)$/i does not work as expected

Tags: regex

I have this regex for email validation (assume only x@y.com, abc@defghi.org, something@anotherhting.edu are valid)

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com)|(edu)|(org)$/i
```

But **@abc.edu** and **abc@xyz.eduorg** are both valid as to the regex above. Can anyone explain why that is?

My approach:

1. there should be at least one character or number before @
2. then there comes @
3. there should be at least one character or number after @ and before .
4. the string should end with either edu, com, or org.

Comment: Not an answer, but relevant: http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: What about all the people with email addresses like `wearewatchingyou@us.gov` and people from other countries like `bigleader@uk.co` or people who have email addresses like `first.last@something.com`.  It's clear you have no idea on what constitutes a valid email address, so I suggest you use someone else's regex.

Comment: Thanks but I am practicing regex now. I need to know why I am wrong.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yN1kJ7/1

Comment: @Robert Mckee thank you for your reply it is just a regex practice.

Comment: If you use a website such as [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) you can view a complete explanation of your pattern and what it's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(com|edu|org)$/i
```

and it should become clear - you need to group those alternatives, otherwise you can match any string that has 'edu' in it, or any string that ends with org. To put it another way, your version matches any of these patterns

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com)`
- `(edu)`
- `(org)$`

*It's worth pointing out that the original poster is using this as a regex learning exercise. This would be a terrible regex for actual production use! It's a thorny problem - see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for a lot more depth.*

Comment: This does what the original poster wanted, albeit still a terrible regex for email validation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: The A-Z is unnecessary with the `i` switch, you can remove them all.

Answer (score 3):

Your grouping parentheses are incorrect:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(com|edu|org)$/i
```

Can also just use one case as you're using the `i` modifier:

```
    /^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.(com|edu|org)$/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

*N.B. you were also missing a `+` from the second set, I assume this was just a typo...*

Comment: If you include the `/i` modifier (which we can infer the OP's regex parser supports, since he used it), why not also remove the `A-Z` from the ranges in your answer?

Comment: Well, you hadn't yet when I posted that comment. :)

Comment: haha I know, it was a further edit after I noticed the `/i` flag - just pulling your leg ;)

Comment: PICTURES! Good answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is the equivalent of matching something that:

Begins with [a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9].com

contains edu

or ends with org

What you were looking for was:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.(com|edu|org)$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex looks ok.

I guess you are looking using a find function in stead of a match function

Without specifying what you use it is a bit difficult, but in Python you would write

```
import re
pattern = re.compile ('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com)|(edu)|(org)$')
re.match('@abc.edu') # fails, use this to validate an input
re.search('@abc.edu') # matches, finds the edu
```

Comment: Not the easiest answer to follow, but what you're saying is essentially correct in that we assume the code is finding sub-match and therefore returning true. On that basis I'll give you an upvote as this is technically what the OP has asked

Answer (score -2):

Try to use it:
[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.(com|edu|org)+$

U forget about `+` modificator if u want to catch any combinations of (com|edu|org)

Upd: as i see second [a-zA-Z0-9] u missed `+` too

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sry, but why? http://pythex.org/?regex=[a-zA-Z0-9]%2B%40[a-zA-Z0-9]%2B\.%28com|edu|org%29%2B&test_string=a%40aacomcomcomcom&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: @RuslanGalimov, you are failing to terminate. http://pythex.org/?regex=%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%40%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%5C.(com%7Cedu%7Corg)%2B&test_string=a%40example.comsomeotherstring&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: Your updated regex also matches the string `1@blorgorg`. You might want to try testing your regex with things you know should fail, in addition to ones that you know should work.